# Parallax Video effect on div

Tags: html, css

I searched on stack but can't seem to find a solution that works.
My Website has two parallax effects on two separate videos inside two separate div's.
first one works fine.

How the first ones HTML looks

```
<div class = "divVideo">
    <video autoplay muted loop class="Video">
        <source src="Videos/Walk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your Browser does not support Video Element.
    </video>
</div>

CSS:

.divVideo{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.Video {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

The second one has a similar HTML code I use the same CSS attributes and it doesn't work. It just shows the previous video in parallax in that 2nd div.

I also tried to change the `position to relative` but that just removes parallax and shows the video that I want as normal(as it should).

Also when I remove the CSS code for my second video div and just have:

```
.divVideo2 {
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the css for the second video

```
.Video2 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

his does not do anything to the 2nd video class until I apply the CSS attributes.
It just displays the actual video size.

Comment: please include the HTML and CSS for both videos together

Comment: I added it but it's same as the other one